# How to choose between compiling ARM assembly file if iOS device and using regular C if iOS simulator

Tags: iphone, c, compiler-construction, assembly, arm

In one of projects I have a file written in ARM assembly that uses NEON to optimize a calculation I am doing it. I also have a file that does the exact same thing except that it is written in C. Currently I just comment out the C functions that are being defined in assembly and just add a

```
extern void myFunction();
```

to the C file.  What i would like to do is have this in the C file

```
#ifdef device
extern void myFunction();
#else
void myFunction() {
   /* code here */
}
#endif
```

I would also need something similar in the assembly file but im not sure how to do preprocessor directives in ARM assembly.

So to sum all this up im looking for a preprocessor definition that tells me what device im am building for and a way to use preprocessor directives in assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your C file:

```
#if defined __arm__
extern void myFunction();
#else
void myFunction() {
   /* code here */
}
#endif
```

In your assembly file:

```
#if defined __arm__
/* code here */
#endif
```

(Xcode applies the C preprocessor to .s files as well).

Comment: Thanks that worked!! I had something similar before but i scrapped it because the preprocessor definition TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR was not available in my assembly file but __arm__ is.